# Why are derivatives and antiderivatives defined only on intervals?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I've a question on derivatives and antiderivatives.

From the definition I know$^{1}$ antiderivatives are defined only on intervals. If I got it, that's mainly because in a interval is possible to use the Mean Value Theorem that guarantees that two antiderivatives differ just from a constant. But are there other reason for this?

Moreover it is not clear to me why also derivatives are defined only on intervals. Firstly the derivative is defined in a single point of course but then it is extended only on intervals and not on other kind of sets. Is there a particular reason for that?

$^{1}$ Considered a function $f$ defined on a interval $I$, a  function $F(x)$ is said to be an antiderivative of $f$ on the interval $I$ if $F'(x)=f(x) \forall x \in I$

Comment: What types of other domains would you expect derivatives to be defined on?  Disconnected sets?

Comment: Yes, for istance if $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ then $f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}$ on two disconnected intervals

Comment: Could you say where this definition you mention comes from? There's no reason to _define_ derivatives and antiderivatives only on intervals (and I don't recall ever seeing this done), though things may not work as naively expected on sets that aren't intervals precisely for the reason you mention: The Mean Value Theorem does assume differentiability on an interval, and this hypothesis cannot be relaxed.

Comment: @Bye_World: Both the Riemann integral and the derivative can be very well defined on disconnected sets (think of $(1,2) \cup (3,4)$) so I don't get your comment.

Comment: I wasn't trying to *say* anything.  I was just trying to get OP to clarify what he meant and hopefully give us a clue as to his level of study.

Comment: Your definition is crucially flawed: such a function $F(x)$ is said to be _an_ antiderivative (not _the_ antiderivative) of $f$.

Comment: @midu10: Given your edit, the answer is "for simplicity", not because there's any technical reason to restrict the definitions to intervals. Definitions are made for convenience, not necessarily for maximum generality.

Answer (score 1):

You do not state your mathematical level, so judging from your question I shall assume you to be a beginner. At this level, then, it is paedagogically wise to define those concepts as you have said.

Otherwise, the concepts of "derivative" and "antiderivative" are defined usually on open sets (of which open intervals are the best example). Sometimes they may even be defined on an even larger class of sets, but open sets should be enough.

The concept of "Riemann integral" is defined on Jordan measureable sets, of which intervals are just particular cases.

The thing is that the fundamental theorem of calculus (the Leibniz-Newton theorem) that connects the Riemann integral and antiderivatives makes sense only on intervals.